# Seperate simple email server and dedicated http server

Tags: domain-name-system, email-server

I've setup a new dedicated server (Ubuntu) to host my sites from so I can build more complex web applications but I don't need nearly as much complexity from my email setup. Is it possible to split traffic and use a seperate email server much like a when you would pay for a managed server for email.

I'm not sure if this is advisable or possible but there are two ways I could imagine it happening, split requests at the Dns level or somehow have my dedicated server bounce email requests to another server

Has anybody achieved anything like this before?

Comment: Hi! What is it your asking? Does mail and web need to be on the same server? No.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just setup an [MX record](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mx_record) for your domain DNS that points to some other server that hosts the mail for your domain and it will end up there. This is an absolute standard requirement.

Comment: As a sidenote this is only good when talking about incoming mail. If your webapp needs to send mail from say a PHP script you will still need a proper MTA to get the mail out. You can certainly set up another server to act as a relay for that domain. However, it would be easier to configure it locally on the same server as the web server